# How do I convert a floating point number to negaquaternary base (base -4?)

Tags: math, radix, complex-numbers

I am trying to convert a number to a nega-quaternary base (as a step in producing the Quater-imaginary base for a complex number). But I can't seem to wrap my head around what to do with the decimals.
How do I implement this? (using java/javascrtip/C#/C/C++/python/ruby or any other similar programming language)?
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_base#To_any_negative_base has code samples for the integer and I mostly understand that, but I fail to make it work for decimals :(

Can anyone help?

Comment: Think of a number as a sum over powers of the base multiplied by their corresponding coefficients (the digits). The fractional component corresponds to a sum over *negative powers* of the base. Modulo arithmetic can still be used but you might need to code the operations explicitly instead of using `%` (or use `fmod` in C).

Answer (score 0):

With a little more googling I managed to find this piece of code in python that does the trick!

https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2120385/514618

The Python code from that discussion is

```
from math import floor
def to_nb(num, base, prec=-15):
    "converts a real from base 10 to negative base (base < -1)"

    digits = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    newval = ""

    if base >= -1 or base < -len(digits):
        raise ValueError('invalid base')

    P = 0; base = abs(base)  # ref. defines method for -base where base > 0
    lb, rb, X = -base / (base+1.), 1 / (base+1.), num

    while not lb <= X < rb:
        P += 1
        X = num / (-base) ** P

    def T(x): return -base * x - floor( -base * x - lb)

    while P >= prec:  # conversion step
        d = int(floor(-base*X - lb))
        X = T(X)
        if P == 0 and '.' not in newval:  # add radix point
            newval = newval + '.'
        if d == base:  # if this happens, you do this (see Ito ref.)
            newval = newval + digits[d-1]+ digits[0]
        else:
            newval = newval + digits[d]
        P -= 1
    return newval
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you show no code of your own, I'll just present an algorithm without code.

My basic idea is to multiply the given number by a power of the base to make the digits we are interested in to the left of the point. We then round the number to the nearest integer. Then use the code you already have to get the nega-quaternary or similar representation as a string. Finally, insert the point at the proper place in the string which in effect divides out the power of the base. If needed, round off the last digit.

The first step is to multiply by an *even* power of the base. The negative-base representation means that if we multiply a nega-quaternary number, which has base `-4`, by `(-4)^2`, namely `16`, its nega-quaternary representation will have the same digits as the original number. The only difference is that the point has been moved two spaces. So if you want your answer to have `prec` number of digits, round `prec` up to an even number (itself if `prec` is even, `prec+1` if it is odd). Then multiply your given number by `(-4)^roundedprec`. If `prec` was odd, you may want to truncate or round off the last digit to get the desired number of digits.